# ffmpegのオプション -c:vについて質問です。

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffmpeg

raspividで取得した動画をffmpegの`-c:v`でコーデックを指定してエンコードするとProtocol not foundとエラーがでます。
コマンドは

```
ffmpeg test -y -i -c:v libx264 test01.mp4
```

これでやっています。testはraspividで取得した動画です。
`c:v`を使わずにmp4にエンコードするとmp4の動画ができます。

なぜ`c:v`を使うとProtocol not foundがでるのかの原因がわかりません。
どなたか教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score 3):

オプションの順番が間違っていませんか？入力ファイル名は `-i` の直後に指定します。

```
ffmpeg -i test -c:v libx264 test01.mp4
```

なぜ Protocol not found というエラーになったのかはわかりませんが・・・。

[ffmpegの使い方：tech.ckme.co.jp](http://tech.ckme.co.jp/ffmpeg.shtml)

Comment: FYI: ffmpegでは入力ソースとしてさまざまな[プロトコル](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html)をサポートしているので、今回のケースでは`-i -c:v`部分が"`-c`という未知のプロトコル"に解釈されたようです。

Comment: なるほど、、、
問題は解決しました！
オプションの使い方がダメだったんですね
もっと勉強します。ありがとうございました！！